# jquery append not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have fumction to append my code.

this code, but this append not work. what wrong, help me please ?

```
var start = moment('<?php echo $start; ?>', 'YYYYMMDD');
var end = moment('<?php echo $end; ?>', 'YYYYMMDD');

function cb(start, end) {
  $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

  alert(start.format('YYYYMMDD'));
  $('body').append($('<form/>')
    .attr({
      'action': './riwayatTransaksi',
      'method': 'post',
      'id': 'replacer'
    })
    .append($('<input/>')
      .attr({
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'start',
        'value': start.format('YYYYMMDD')
      })
    )
    .append($('<input/>')
      .attr({
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'end',
        'value': end.format('YYYYMMDD')
      })
    )
  ).find('#replacer').submit();
}
```

how i call cb() fuction, but function .daterangepicker is still error "is not a function" but in my console thats work

```
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
                '7 Hari Terakhir': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                '30 Hari Terakhir': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'Bulan Ini': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Bulan Lalu': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, cb);
```

Comment: How do you call cb() function? Do you call it at all?

Comment: @slon no i call cb()  it all. wait i will edit my quastion and warite how i call cb() fuction

Comment: "is not a function"? Is your $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({}) function inside of $(function () { ...}); ?

Comment: @slon yes i put in $(document).ready(function () {});

Comment: If you are getting an error on .daterangepicker, cb() may not get called.

Comment: @slon emmm, i just want to append form, but its not work. i put on read function to add from. but still not work.

Comment: the error is `function .daterangepicker is still error "is not a function"`, means you dont include daterangepicker js or you have placed it in wrong order. check that

Comment: @AkhilAravind oke, my browser function .daterangepicker is still error "is not a function" but in my program still work. and then fuction append its not work

Comment: "but in my program still work" , what do you mean by this.. is this an error or is it working

Comment: @AkhilAravind daterangepicker  in console its work and showed data, but stil have error, i dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace this code jquery:

```
$('body').append($('<form/>',
    {
      'action': './riwayatTransaksi',
      'method': 'post',
      'id': 'replacer'
    })
    .append($('<input/>',
    {
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'start',
        'value': start.format('YYYYMMDD')
      }))
     .append($('<input/>',
      {
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'end',
        'value': end.format('YYYYMMDD')
      })))
    .find('#replacer').submit();
```